# How do i change this jQuery code into pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Prelude: I'm sure this code is ugly so feel free to suggest a better way.

The goal: making a little web store that lets people preview their different configurations of a given product (a belt) as they make their selections. (e.g. red belt with a gold buckle vs red belt with a silver buckle, etc.).

You can see a working version here: http://solomongiles.com/demos/deadcowbelts/choose-a-belt/trial2.html.

And here's my ugly jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("img").addClass("hide");
    $("img.belt-black").removeClass("hide");
    $("img.buckle-gold").removeClass("hide");
    $("img.coins-gold").removeClass("hide");
    

    $("input.belt-black").click(function(event){
       $("img.belt-black").removeClass("hide");
       $("img.belt-brown").addClass("hide");
       $("img.belt-red").addClass("hide");      
     });
    $("input.belt-brown").click(function(event){
       $("img.belt-black").addClass("hide");
       $("img.belt-brown").removeClass("hide");
       $("img.belt-red").addClass("hide");      
     });
    $("input.belt-red").click(function(event){
       $("img.belt-black").addClass("hide");
       $("img.belt-brown").addClass("hide");
       $("img.belt-red").removeClass("hide");       
     });
    
    $("input.buckle-gold").click(function(event){
       $("img.buckle-gold").removeClass("hide");
       $("img.buckle-silver").addClass("hide");
     });
    $("input.buckle-silver").click(function(event){
       $("img.buckle-gold").addClass("hide");
       $("img.buckle-silver").removeClass("hide");
     });

    $("input.coins-gold").click(function(event){
       $("img.coins-gold").removeClass("hide");
       $("img.coins-silver").addClass("hide");
     });
    $("input.coins-silver").click(function(event){
       $("img.coins-gold").addClass("hide");
       $("img.coins-silver").removeClass("hide");
     });
    
 });
```

Thank you community! You're great. :)

Jon

Comment: Exactly why do you want to rewrite it non jQuery javascript?

Comment: Sort of a strange request.  If you haven't gotten a solid grasp of jquery (you describe your own code as 'ugly'), pure javascript is even more difficult.  What are you trying to accomplish by ditching jquery?

Comment: well, the thing is: the client for whom i am designing this site owns a really old mac and his version of safari just won't run the demo that i've built. and it seems like the issue might be that it relies on jquery. i'm hoping that if i remove jquery from the picture then it will be more cross browser friendly. :)

Comment: In general getting rid of jquery will make your code *less* cross browser friendly. What version of safari?

Answer (score 3):

[getElementsByClassName](http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/)

[add/remove class](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/dom/class_manipulation.php)

[add events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a method without JQuery, that uses the cascading in CSS instead of hiding and showing each element. The class name of the belt `div` is set to control which images are visible.

I put the text for the radio buttons in `label` elements and linked them to the radio buttons, so now you can click on the text also, not only the radio button itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Custom Belt Prototype</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

var belt = 'black', buckle = 'gold', coins = 'gold';

function setClass() {
   document.getElementById('belt').className = 'belt-'+belt+' buckle-'+ buckle+' coins-'+coins;
}

function setBelt(color) {
   belt = color;
   setClass();
}

function setBuckle(color) {
   buckle = color;
   setClass();
}

function setCoins(color) {
   coins = color;
   setClass();
}

</script>

<style type="text/css">

body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#belt { position: relative; top: 10px; margin: 0 auto; width: 652px; }
#belt-triggers { position: relative; top: 100px; margin: 0 auto; width: 110px; }

#belt img { position: absolute; display: none; }
#belt.belt-black .belt-black,
#belt.belt-brown .belt-brown,
#belt.belt-red .belt-red,
#belt.buckle-gold .buckle-gold,
#belt.buckle-silver .buckle-silver,
#belt.coins-gold .coins-gold,
#belt.coins-silver .coins-silver { display: block; }

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="belt" class="belt-black buckle-gold coins-gold">

<img class="belt-black" src="faux-belt/belt-black.png" alt="belt-black" width="652" height="75"/>
<img class="belt-brown" src="faux-belt/belt-brown.png" alt="belt-brown" width="652" height="75"/>
<img class="belt-red" src="faux-belt/belt-red.png" alt="belt-red" width="652" height="75"/>

<img class="buckle-gold" src="faux-belt/buckle-gold.png" alt="buckle-gold" width="652" height="75"/>
<img class="buckle-silver" src="faux-belt/buckle-silver.png" alt="buckle-silver" width="652" height="75"/>

<img class="coins-gold" src="faux-belt/coins-gold.png" alt="coins-gold" width="652" height="75"/>
<img class="coins-silver" src="faux-belt/coins-silver.png" alt="coins-silver" width="652" height="75"/>

</div>

<div id="belt-triggers">

<input class="belt-black" name="belt" id="belt_black" type="radio" checked="checked" onclick="setBelt('black');" /> <label for="belt_black">belt: black</label><br />
<input class="belt-brown" name="belt" id="belt_brown" type="radio" onclick="setBelt('brown');" /> <label for="belt_brown">belt: brown</label><br />
<input class="belt-red" name="belt" id="belt_red" type="radio" onclick="setBelt('red');" /> <label for="belt_red">belt: red</label><br /><br />

<input class="buckle-gold" name="buckle" id="buckle_gold" type="radio" checked="checked" onclick="setBuckle('gold');" /> <label for="buckle_gold">buckle: gold</label><br />
<input class="buckle-silver" name="buckle" id="buckle_silver" type="radio" onclick="setBuckle('silver');" /> <label for="buckle_silver">buckle: silver</label><br /><br />

<input class="coins-gold" name="coins" id="coins_gold" type="radio" checked="checked" onclick="setCoins('gold');" /> <label for="coins_gold">coins: gold</label><br />
<input class="coins-silver" name="coins" id="coins_silver" type="radio" onclick="setCoins('silver');" /> <label for="coins_silver">coins: silver</label>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why the downvote (whoever that was)? If you don't say what it is that you don't like, it's rather pointless...

Comment: That's odd... What specifically do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens?