# Style the active thumbnail in an image gallery

Tags: javascript, css

Here's a sample gallery:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Slideshow</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
#large {width:448px; height:336px; background:#000 url(http://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ugFamEhbqPo/Thc6hoArbwI/AAAAAAAAABA/PFeHcJhR4Xw/s800/image1.jpg) no-repeat center;}
#thumbs {padding-top:12px; overflow:auto; white-space:nowrap; width:448px;}
img {padding:1px; width:80px; height:60px;}
img:hover {background:#00F;}
</style>
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="large"></div>  
<div id="thumbs"> 
<img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt="" onclick="document.getElementById('large').style.backgroundImage='url(http://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ugFamEhbqPo/Thc6hoArbwI/AAAAAAAAABA/PFeHcJhR4Xw/s800/image1.jpg)';">
<img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-JU5a-eDnOSg/Thc7g5UkwLI/AAAAAAAAABI/9aCyCMixWb4/s800/thumb2.jpg" alt="" onclick="document.getElementById('large').style.backgroundImage='url(http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-u5BHGxpr0rg/Thc6hLbDRKI/AAAAAAAAAA8/IvQWzJBvqjg/s800/image2.jpg)';">
<img src="http://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-TdbbNGFbDNk/Thc7g0IBSsI/AAAAAAAAABM/pxpntZaTVoQ/s800/thumb3.jpg" alt="" onclick="document.getElementById('large').style.backgroundImage='url(http://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-4AMWSfi8q7A/Thc6haUv1QI/AAAAAAAAABE/oRdTWawPi_c/s800/image3.jpg)';">
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

I wonder how I can highlight the active thumbnail so its background remains blue until I click another one.

Thanks in advance!

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution in pure JavaScript that is in tune with what you're already doing:

http://jsfiddle.net/drNqx/3/

Add this simple function in the `<head>` of the document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reset()
{
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
    {
        imgs[i].style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    }
}
</script>
```

The place this in front of what you already have in the `onclick` for each thumbnail image:

```
reset();this.style.backgroundColor='#00f';
```

To highlight the first thumbnail as the default, add this below the `reset()` function:

```
function init()
{
    document.getElementById('img1').style.backgroundColor='#00F';
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Seems good! How can I set the first thumbnail to be active when the gallery loads? i.e I'd like it to have a blue background when the page loads.

Comment: @RainLover I just edited my answer to incorporate the first thumbnail as the default.

Comment: Perfect! I made some changes into it:[link](http://jsfiddle.net/drNqx/6/). There's just one thing I'm not happy about: is there a way to put the onclick event in the head and make the body less cluttered?

Comment: `document.getElementById("foo").onclick = function () {
  alert('foo'); // do your stuff
};`

Comment: Does that mean I should go through two loops: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/drNqx/7/)

Comment: You could. Or you could just write them out individually. It's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/DEn6r/2/

**Jquery code to add:**

```
$('img').click(function() {
          $('img').not(this).removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
});​
```

**CSS to add:**

```
img.active{background:#00f;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can it be done with pure JavaScript?

Comment: Here is a question related to converting code from Jquery to javascript.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252083/how-do-i-change-this-jquery-code-into-pure-javascript

Comment: @RainLover I posted an answer that is pure javascript.

Comment: @SVS: Thanks for the link, but I still have difficulty converting it from jQuery to simple JavaScript. I'd be grateful if you helped me with this!

Answer (score 0):

/* You need to add class to active thumb image  using Jquery . make sure to add jquery path*/

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

$("#thumbs img").click(function(){

$("#thumbs img").removeClass("selected");/* this will remove selected class from all images*/
$(this).addClass("selected"); /* this will add 'selected' class to particular image where you clicked */

});
});

in css you can give whatever style you want to give using css

<style>
#thumbs img.selected
{
border:2px solid blue;
background-color:#eee;
}
#thumbs img
{
padding:5px;
}

</style>
```